# How to show $A$ is a bounded linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $A:H \rightarrow H$ is a linear operator such that $\langle Ax, y\rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle,  \forall x, y \in H$ then how to show $A$ is a bounded linear operator?

Comment: Use Banach Steinhaus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem use principle of uniform boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180495/hellinger-toeplitz-theorem-use-principle-of-uniform-boundedness)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1. Adjoint operators are closed.
2. Closed graph theorem.

EDIT: BTW, this is called the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem.

Comment: A proof using the closed graph theorem can be found e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/255777/545914). Why do we need the closeness of the adjoint? Or are those two ideas for two proofs?

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1:** Use Closed Graph Theorem like Robert Israel suggested.

**Solution 2:** Note that if $\|x\| = 1$ then for all $y \in H$ we have that $|\langle Ax, y \rangle| = |\langle x, Ay \rangle| $ $\leq \|x\| \cdot \|Ay\| = \|Ay\|$. Hence by the uniform boundedness principle we see that $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \| \langle Ax, \cdot \rangle\| < \infty$. Use this as a hint to proceed.