# Suppose that A is a linear map from a Hilbert space H into itself that satisfies <x,Ay> = <Ax, y> for all x, y in H . Show that A is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that A is a linear map from a Hilbert space H into itself that satisfies $\langle x,Ay\rangle=\langle Ax,y\rangle$  for all $x, y$ in $H$ . Show that A is bounded.

Please Give me hints to solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: Try to use Banach-Steinhaus theorem

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180495/hellinger-toeplitz-theorem-use-principle-of-uniform-boundedness